# Is $L^{p}(I,X)\cong L^{p}(I) \widehat{\otimes_{\pi}}X$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products, tensors

It is well known that
$$L^{1}(I,X) \cong L^{1}(I) \widehat{\otimes_{\pi}}X$$
For any compact interval (I,m) with the Lebesgue measure and any Banach space X.
Is it still true when $1<p<\infty$
that
$$L^{p}(I,X) \cong L^{p}(I) \widehat{\otimes_{\pi}}X$$

If not, can we embed one of them in the other ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by $\otimes_\pi$ you mean the projective tensor product then the answer is positive for $p=1$ as you remarked and otherwise it is false. Indeed, take $p=2$ and $X=L_2$. Then $L_2(L_2)$ is a Hilbert space but $L_2\otimes_\pi L_2$ is the dual of the space of compact operators on $L_2$, hence it is non-reflexive.

Comment: What about the relation is there any inclusions or embedding between the two spaces?

Comment: @SaraSurad, yes, because the projective norm is the biggest possible cross-norm and $L_p(X)$ is abstractly a tensor product too.

Comment: I'm so grateful for your valuable answer. Thanks a lot